# Which is the best/feasible between angular-2 cookie and ng2-cookie to implement cookies in angular-2 application?

Tags: angular, cookies

In my application i need to set cookie which is a unique id, that id i am receiving through service and it will be treated as cookie in my angular-2 application, now i have searched in documentation and some sites to setting-up cookie in angular-2 and i came across two library/way first is angular-2 cookie(implementation of angularjs 1.x $cookie service) and second is ng2-cookie, so which should i prefer?
References:

1. https://github.com/salemdar/angular2-cookie
2. https://github.com/BCJTI/ng2-cookies

Answer (score 0):

Well, angular2-cookie seems DEPRECATED in favour of ngx-cookie according to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/salemdar/angular2-cookie).